# quiero poner una mayuscula despues de un punto en c considerando cualquier caso ,hasta el momento tengo esto pero no toma todos los casos posibles

Tags: c, string, programacion-asincrona

hacer que el código convierta en mayúscula la primera letra después de un punto dada una cadena(frase). para esto crearemos un programa que funcione como una maquina descompuesta ya sea agregando una frase con puntos desformada ya sea por mayúsculas o minúsculas así que lo primero que haremos será escanear nuestra frase descompuesta y después la convertiremos todas en minúscula para facilitar nuestro procedimiento,   después crearemos una función que nos permita convertir la primera letra después de cada punto sin importar la cantidad de espacios en una letra mayúscula logrando que nuestra frase se imprima de manera correcta

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define MAX 80
void conv_min(char cadena[MAX],int n);
void imprimir_frase(char cadena[MAX],int n);
int main(void)
{
  char cadena[MAX];
  int tam;
  int num;
  char letra={'l'};
  num=isalpha(letra);
// printf("la letra a es %d",num);
  scanf("%[^\n]",&cadena);
  tam=strlen(cadena);
  //convertir toda la cadena a minusculas para poder comparar la cadena sin problemas
  conv_min(cadena,tam);
  imprimir_frase(cadena,tam);

  return 0;

}
```

la función permite enviar toda la frase y la convierte en minúsculas para facilitar el proceso

```
void conv_min(char cadena[MAX],int n){
  int i;
  char letra;
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    letra=cadena[i];
    //printf("%c ",letra);
    cadena[i]=tolower(letra);
  //  printf("%c ",cadena1[i]);
  }  
}
```

La función nos permite tomar toda la frase y verifica solo los primeros casos después del punto, sin embargo no toma en cuenta todos los casos posibles ya que solo toma en cuenta unos posibles casos

```
void imprimir_frase(char cadena[MAX],int n)
{
  int num=0,i=0;
  char letra;
  char letrain;
  char actual;
  char punto='.';
  char espacio=' ';
  letrain=cadena[0];
  //printf("%c",letrain);
  for(i;i<n-2;i++){
      letra=cadena[i];
      if(cadena[0]==letrain)
    {
      cadena[0]=toupper(letra);

    }
    if(cadena[i]==punto&&cadena[i+1]==espacio){
        cadena[i+2]=toupper(cadena[i+2]);
    }
    if(isalpha(cadena[i+1])==2)
    {
        if(cadena[i]==punto){
            cadena[i+1]=toupper(cadena[i+1]);
        }
    }
   // printf("%c\n",cadena[i]);
  }
  printf("%s",cadena);
}
```

con todos los casos posibles no se puede lograr convertir en mayúsculas ya que requiere encontrar una manera para que nos permite convertir la primera lera después del punto sin importar la cantidad de espacios que se agreguen a este después del cada punto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes recorrer la cadena de modo que al encontrar un punto se establezca una variable `cambiarMayuscula` a `1` y al encontrar una letra, la cambie por una mayúscula si `cambiarMayuscula` es `1`. Con este simple criterio tienes solucionada la mayoría de los casos.

Así:

```
// Según tu código, se supone que todas las letras
// de la cadena ya son minúsculas.
void imprimir_frase(char cadena[MAX],int n)
{
    char cambiarMayuscula = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        char actual = cadena[i];
        char esLetra = actual >= 'a' && actual <= 'z';
        char esPunto = actual == '.';

        if (esLetra && cambiarMayuscula) {
            cadena[i] = toupper(actual);
            cambiarMayuscula = 0;
        }
        else if (esPunto) {
            cambiarMayuscula = 1;
        }
    }
    printf("%s",cadena);
}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##lVNLbtswEN3zFAMHjSXEddRdAVoBsuqmAboskLrBmKJiAhQpkFQKt9BhepYezB1StuzKQNBoIXEe38y8@Ui8FxrN835/pYzQXSVh5UOl7HJ7x84hp8zzv5gIu1ZGiMVDJWsQW3SwsVZzdkW2MhKC6yR8GM0atZdQjPbD/Vf4WDD2YlUFwpqXp0aZLMURWEmDj8RYL0CZACbnA081rVONck@1Qy9fYbN4aJAiRr@c/WIAUzYnLNICNuQA4AWaOpu9e/z@zaxniwM1jzSilNQILUnhESX49jYKly4oB8FWCBoPXoBA5XRedBo9tOgQWltJym@baLkzqlcGWmc3Wjboo86xGel@QcmTiGnx57d07WTonIGCjJ69qV2pO5DGR9fNRqF7wN0gHso0SJ4YtXVZdFGEFpw@KzD0ubnJhwjxSUlQhA41sQ7Z1JqPhJRG@s8yuBj9QL0rYY5zuL4@AisCfs4v3L50JtiTW0ms5TzVPzyqhuwYnIJNy8nhpDSpPeqLddqubaXLhtA5nxAv@pI2@sTqx5OMmz4ISXIvk77S41Oo4U0TNCGupZ8txt3r//e/Gfdex47EDOMMy4KrleFxegQPChOrnAxtNMtgtf1BHUq01KAegPX7/dZqXIK3O/gkXfPnt1myvw).